# Disable touch trail animation

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winjs

I'm developing a Win8 JavaScript app for a tablet and implementing my own touch animation trail - i.e. wherever the user drags their finger(s), my custom animation is left as a trail. However the default windows trail is also being displayed - is there any way to disable this? I've looked in the system-wide settings but there doesn't appear to be anything there, and I've also tried

```
var gestureRecognizer = new Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer();
gestureRecognizer.showGestureFeedback = false;
```

But this didn't help either.

Comment: That looks like a bug to me. I would put it up on Connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer - it's a two-parter. First the "Show visual feedback when touching the screen" checkbox needs unchecking in Pen & Touch settings in control panel. Second, I used `cursor: none` in my CSS on the canvas I didn't want the crosshair or tail to be displayed on.